# How to use value in id second when value change [using javascript]?

Tags: javascript

How to use value in `id="second"` when value change [using javascript]?

For thisd case i tried to alert value from `id="second"`, but not work. How can i do ?

By do not change `set_value_to_second_fn` code.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/cp7ff2fq/
```

...

```
<input id="first" onchange="set_value_to_second_fn()">
<input id="second" onchange="alert_fn()" disabled>
<script>
function set_value_to_second_fn(){
document.getElementById("second").value = document.getElementById("first").value;
}

function alert_fn(){
alert(document.getElementById("second").value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: fiddle works fine, except  of course the `alert_fn` wont get called because the user can't change that input, so `onchange` wont fire - if you think about what it is you are trying to achieve, adding `alert_fn()` to the end of `set_value_to_second_fn()` will be exactly what you want to do - i.e. `https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/cp7ff2fq/1/`

Comment: could you please do not change `set_value_to_second_fn` code.

Comment: I can do what I want in jsfiddle - the code does exactly what (erroneously) you think your code should do - there's also another way - `https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/cp7ff2fq/2/`

Answer (score 0):

This may be available:

```
<script>
    function set_value_to_second_fn() {
        document.getElementById("second").value = document.getElementById("first").value;
        init();
    }

    function alert_fn() {
        alert(document.getElementById("second").value);
    }

    function init() {
        if ("\v" == "v") { // IE browser
            document.getElementById("second").onpropertychange = alert_fn;
        } else { // Other browser
            document.getElementById("second").addEventListener("input", alert_fn(), false);
        }
    }
</script>
```